# c++ MIDI sequencer and smf loader library on windows

Tags: c++, midi

I'm Japanese web engineer.

I'm developing a MIDI Sequencer(SMF player) application running on Windows (XP), using C++ as programming language and Qt as GUI Library. And I'm in trouble now.

For developing this application, I'm searching for MIDI Sequencer library. And Standard MIDI File loader library useful on Windows, but I can't find good one.

For example, jdksmidi, I can't compile successfully; juce, needs Visual Studio environment, and I'm developing in Qt environment and don't want to use ViualStudio; TSE3, Win32.cpp is uncompilable.

Please tell me good some library for MIDI sequencing and smf loading on Windows.

Comment: Regarding the SMF loader, I wrote a header-only version of this a while ago: https://github.com/filmor/star/tree/master/include/utility/midi. You need Boost for this one (although it could be easily modified to use the C++11 standard library (it only uses boost::integer, variant and tuple). You can build a sequencer with that yourself by writing your own visitor.

Answer (score 1):

If anything else works, go for the manual approach:

MIDI input/output: go for pure Windows API

SMF loader:        write your own